# I can't select "filmic" in view transform

Tags: rendering, color-management

OS: windows10 64bit
version:2.83

view transform shows only "standard" and nothing else.I know filmic color management is already installed to blender 2.8. Also every time i download a new version of blender 2.8 it does the exact same thing.
please help me.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFSOy.gif

Comment: Try to download and extract the portable version (.zip), it doesn't require any installation. Blender comes with an OCIO config file and the required look-up tables, including Filmic. Therefore Filmic is available in a clean install.

Comment: my problem is https://developer.blender.org/T51896 this.

i downloaded portable version, (.msi)version, steam version, but i can select only "standard" at view transform. 

my blender has "filmic"  folder (file path : 2.83 -> datafiles->colormanagement ->filmic). However it does not work.(blender does not load this?)

Comment: @Robert Gützkow

Comment: The ticket you've linked seems unrelated to your problem, since that person is able to select Filmic as view transform. Please read  [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685) and create a bug report, if the issue occurs on a clean install with factory default settings. You can link the ticket here, tag me and I'll take a look.

Comment: sorry, the URL was wrong, this is what i want to tell you. https://developer.blender.org/T63974 My problem is the same.@Robert Gützkow
i will report thisproblem.

Comment: I could solve this problem. Thank you so much! @Robert Gützkow
For someone who is in trouble like this, I write the solution.  I installed Blender in the D drive (it is not installed OS, OS is in the C drive),so i tried to install into the C drive. this is the solution for this problem.